# Is there any good tactic to winning air balls?

Tags: pro-evolution-soccer-2012

I've been playing PES for a while, and PES2012 since it came out.
I wondered, is there a good tactic to winning air balls (like when goalkeeper kicks a long ball, or just in general), or am I limited to tapping X (pass) multiple times to try and get it?

Is there a way to be "aggressive" in order to get the ball?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to control the ball using R2 as well, but your opponent may jump and beat you to the ball.

Another option is to use the square button to try to push your opponent, but you may commit a foul or shoot the ball instead.

You can try to better position the player with the left stick (or I hear experts are using super-cancel first, but when I try this I can't position my player near the ball at all).

P.S. These are things I've done in previous versions of PES, as I don't have 2012 yet.

P.P.S. I'm an average player and would love to read what others have to say as well.